# Android testcase with database and access to TestProject's resources

Tags: android, sqlite, android-resources

I i found a way to access the Resources of the TestProject

[Accessing resources in an android test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249751/accessing-resources-in-an-android-test-project)

but when i use the ActivityTestCase instead of AndroidTestcase i cannot access the database

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:54)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.idExists(BaseDaoImpl.java:805)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:335)
```

is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my Problem:

i use now InstrumentationTestCase (i think ActivityTestCase would work either)

The Problem was that there are two contexts

```
    Context mainProjectContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    Context testProjectContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
```

now i can gat the resources from testProjectContext  and let the database run with mainProjectContext