# Creating notification from InstrumentationTestCase

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, notifications, android-instrumentation

I want to test from a unit test whether a notification is able to play a custom sound from assets.
The test is not meant to verify anything, I wrote it as a quick way of demonstrating a feature without cluttering the main app code.

So In the test project, I added a wav file inside `/res/raw`. I'll be using this URL with the notification builder:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://<main app package name>/testsound.wav");
```

That URL should work according to the questions I've been reading in SO. Let's assume it works.

Now because I didn't want to include the test wav file in the main project's `/res/raw` folder but in the test project one, I'm forced to make my unit test extend from `InstrumentationTestCase` so that I can access the resources in the test project.

Here's the code:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getInstrumentation().getContext());
    ...
    builder.setSound(path, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    ...
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getInstrumentation().getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

The `notify` call is throwing the following exception:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid 10198 gave package <main app package name> which is owned by uid 10199
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:611)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:187)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:140)
    ... 
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1873)
```

I've tracked this exception down to the `NotificationManagerService` class:

```
    void checkCallerIsSystemOrSameApp(String pkg) {
        int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
        if (UserHandle.getAppId(uid) == Process.SYSTEM_UID || uid == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = AppGlobals.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                    pkg, 0, UserHandle.getCallingUserId());
            if (!UserHandle.isSameApp(ai.uid, uid)) {
                throw new SecurityException("Calling uid " + uid + " gave package"
                        + pkg + " which is owned by uid " + ai.uid);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            throw new SecurityException("Unknown package " + pkg + "\n" + re);
        }
    }
```

Apparently the exception doesn't have anything to do with the custom sound, but with the fact that we're creating a notification from an `InstrumentationTestCase`.

Is there a way of testing this? I remember having created notifications from `AndroidTestCase` in the past, but if I do that then I wont be able to access the test wav file. I could create a jar with the wav and drop the jar in the test project's lib folder, but that would be hiding the file, and other programmers might have a hard time looking for it if they need to replace it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to do get the sound to work from an `AndroidTestCase`.
The wav file was added to the test project's raw folder and was not included in the main project as intended.

The URL for the notification was like this:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://<test project package name>/" + R.raw.air_horn);
```

And the builder was obtained as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've been a bit puzzled by the question. So I wrote small Instrumentation test.

For the sake of asserting, I marked the test to run only on API 23 (`getActiveNotifications` seems to be unavailable before), but it works fine on older APIs as well.

**The trick is to use `getTargetContext()` instead of `getContext()`:**

```
public final class MainActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void testSendNotification() {
        final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.cancel(42);
        assertEquals(0, manager.getActiveNotifications().length);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification test")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("Hello, Mister Smith")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification);

        manager.notify(42, builder.build());

        assertEquals(1, manager.getActiveNotifications().length);
    }
}
```

It works like a charm:

[image]

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Yep, this works. The wav file is played as expected. The only drawback is that you need an activity from your main project.

Comment: @MisterSmith but you've been asking about **Instrumentation test**, not unit test. Your answer doesn't reflect the question you ask.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was assuming that in order to access a resource in the test project I had to use instrumentation, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249751/accessing-resources-in-an-android-test-project)). But it turned out it works from a regular unit test. Thanks anyway.