# Error: unable to open database on sqlite3

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, sqlite, console

I'm working on Android and using Eclipse to develop and the emulator to test my application, I'm trying to insert the content from an ArrayList into a database, but when I try to access to the database's information through the console I get the following message:

`Error: unable to open database /data/data/my.package/databases/ars.db : unable to open database file`

So far I know the database is being created correctly since every time I insert a row the SQLiteDatabase's insert method returns the id of the row created and so far I have run my application 6 times and the last id I got was 18.

I'm trying to access to the database the following way:

`#sqlite3 /data/data/my.package/databases/ars.db`

and then when I try :

`sqlite>.tables`

I get the error message. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get permission to access to the database data? Is it because I'm using the emulator instead of an Android device? Thanks for any piece of advice you can give.

Comment: You can read this may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563728/random-exception-android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-unable-to-open-databas

Comment: no that didn't work, I can access to it from my application, it's through the console that I have problems.

Comment: Almost having same problem

Comment: but i figured out that problem was in the way how  i access my db. Try your DB without .db like ; sqlite3 /data/data/my.package/databases/ars